# Three js smooth shading appearing flat

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl-format

I'm loading `.stl` files, applying `MeshStandardMaterial` without touching the `flatShading` property as by default it is `false`.

[image]

The result looks very flat to me. If I try setting `flatShading: true` the result is the same.

I've tried everything I could think of but have ran out of ideas - any suggestion would be welcome, thanks.

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
geometry.normalizeNormals();
```

Comment: What are you doing different from [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=stl#webgl_loader_stl)? Can you load your shape in that example? Does it work there? Can you load the shapes from the example in your code. Do they work? etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The result looks very flat to me. If I try setting flatShading: true the result is the same.

`STLLoader` always returns a non-indexed buffer geometry (unconnected triangle soup). That means the geometry's faces share no vertices and thus using `BufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals()` can not produce normals required for smooth shading.

Also recomputing bounding volumes and the usage of `BufferGeometry.normalizeNormals()` are unrelated to this issue.

You can try to solve this issue by ensuring the asset comes with normals that allow smooth shading. Or you give [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices) a try which produces an indexed geometry by merging vertices.

Comment: Thanks! Had to use `Geometry` instead of `BufferGeometry` to gain access to `mergeVerteces`, 90% of the time it looks good now, but there are a few problem spots where computed normals just are not correct - will move to using a different file format.